# How to access an Akka actor "from the outside" of the app? via its pid or equivalent?

Tags: akka

Context: a stateless webservice (running on Glassfish) which uses Akka actors to run jobs. Results from this service are stored in a database.

The webservice client is used to launch jobs by the web service. This part works fine. I need now that in a different session, the web client can send an instruction for a job (my Akka app) to interrupt in an orderly fashion. This would be done best by sending a message to the top actor, which would then dispatch further messages to its actors.

The problem is, I don't know how to send a message "from the outside" to an actor of an akka app which is already running?

Any pointer would be appreciated!

Comment: The ActorRef should be enough the send a message to an actor from anywhere

Comment: Could you elaborate please? Sessions are stateless (I edited the question to indicate it), so I am not sure how this impacts the answer.

Comment: I don't really know much about Glassfish. My question was - can you somehow obtain the ActorRef of the actor which you want to access? If you do, you can use it to send messages even if you're not within an actual actor.

Comment: oh do you mean accessing an actor by using the "Actor Path Anchor" as discussed here? http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/general/addressing.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can think of two different ways of communicating with your actor.

1. If your client knows the name of the actor it wants to send the message to and Remoting (http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/remoting.html) is enabled, you could create an ActorSystem client-side, get the ActorSelection to the actor in question and use this ActorSelection to send the message.
2. You could use something like spray (http://spray.io/documentation/) to create a service that listens for any messages from your client.

I did something like this a while ago to talk to my ActorSystem from a Webclient. Which kind of looked like this:

```
import akka.actor.{ActorLogging, Actor}
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import spray.http._
import HttpMethods._


class LoggingService extends Actor with ActorLogging {
  implicit val timeout = 1.second


  def receive = {
    case HttpRequest(POST, "/logging", _, entity, _) =>
      val interaction = entity.asString.asJson.convertTo[UserActivity]

      interaction match {
        case UserActivity(program, time, "WebActivity:begin", uri, title) => ...
      }

    case h: HttpRequest =>
      sender ! HttpResponse(StatusCodes.NotFound, entity = "Unknown resource!")
  }
}
```

To the ActorSystem I added the following to start the service:

```
val system = ActorSystem("logging-server")
val ioBridge = IOExtension(system).ioBridge

val requestHandler = system.actorOf(Props[LoggingService])

val server = system.actorOf(
    props = Props(new HttpServer(ioBridge, SingletonHandler(requestHandler))),
    name = "logging-service"
)


server ! HttpServer.Bind(uri, port)
```